# How make my ContainerRequestFilter called on @ServerEndpoint onOpen?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websocket, jax-rs

I have a web socket `@ServerEndpoint` that has an annotation which my filter listens to. But my filter is never called (my filter *is* called on normal JAX-RS resources)

how can i make my filter get called for a web socket endpoint?

```
@ServerEndpoint("/push/register")
public class WebSocketListener
{
    @OnOpen
    @MyFilter
    public void open(Session session)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The filter:

```
@MyFilter
@Provider
@Priority( Priorities.AUTHENTICATION )
public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter
{
    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAX-RS filters have nothing to do with websocket endpoints and name binding should not work either.

---

You could implement [`Filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) from the Servlet API using the same URI defined in the [`@ServerEndpoint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpoint.html) annotation, then you'll be able to intercept the handshake request.

However filters won't intercept WebSocket frames.

```
@WebFilter("/push/register")
public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, 
                         FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        ...

        chain.doFilter(request, response);    
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

Comment: This works for initial connection, but not with `onMessage`. Any idea how i can have it called for that method too?

Comment: I do, and as a result it goes to my `@OnOpen` method, but the filter is never called on the `@OnMessage` method